# Apache 2 and PHP 5.3 via MacPorts?

Tags: apache-2.2, php5, osx-snow-leopard, mac-osx

I have install MacPortsed and I have installed Apache 2 and PHP 5.3 but I can't get Apache 2 to work with PHP 5.3.

I have tried to unload and load it again, I don't know how I can reinstall apache from MacPorts or how I can get PHP 5.3 to work with this.

I have run this command

```
sudo port install php5 +apache2 +pear
```

But my web server is not running PHP 5 right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a particular reason you're wanting to use the MacPorts version of PHP and Apache? Apple has Apache 2 and PHP 5.3 preloaded for Snow Leopard Server.

Have you edited your appropriate httpd.conf file to include `php5.so` (not commented out)?

For example with Apple's default installation PHP is disabled and you need to enable PHP 5 either through Server Admin (where the Sites section under Web provides a basic GUI for httpd.conf) or editing `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf`. For MacPorts the appropriate file is at `/opt/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf`.

Comment: Tanks for help, that you say its problem nr. 1 :) and the ordre problem its i need to include "mod_php.conf" file, tanks for respons :)